# Javascript animation on hover

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hover

[image]How to make an animation of a moving dot
along the edge of the figure using arrays and eventlistner?
Animation starts when you hover the cursor over it and it returns to its place along the same path
same like transition keyframes in css. For loop is mentioned in the task and couples "left/right" "top/bottom"

Will you explain to me how I should go about this task?

Comment: You should add more details, to obtain a response. What are you trying to do? Have you any code to share?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSNAME');
    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
            // Your Code Here
        })
    })
</script>
```